# How to loop through Selectize options and determine which are existing ID's and new entries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, selectize.js

I'm using [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) to build a dropdown of `keywords` associated with a record from a separate MySQL table. I have Selectize set to allow selection of existing records in the keyword table, but also add new keywords. So when I look at the post,

```
 Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Test Record [keywords] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => New Keyword 1 [4] => New Keyword 2 ))
```

So you can see that I've selected 3 existing keywords and 2 new keywords:

```
 id = 1
 id = 2
 id = 3
 new = New Keyword 1
 new = New Keyword 2
```

What I want to do is update the record with the associated keywords, but first I need to add the new keywords to the keyword table, then do the association. In order to do this, I need to be able to distinguish between `existing and new` keywords in the post array and loop through adding the new ones, then updating the association to the record.

One way would be to lookup each keyword as I loop through the array to see if it exists in the `keywords` table, if not, then add and continue. This feels like a lot of extra overhead so if there was a way to know which elements in the post array were `existing` and which were `new` I could just loop through the new ones and add them without wasting time to lookup each one.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Why not just use 'insert if not exists'?

Comment: Or, 'INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'?  The UPDATE part can be nonsense, like 0+0 or id=id.

Comment: @CharlesEF the issue is that Selectize sends over the values in the same location in the array. So if I try to insert, the existing ones are the id and the new ones are the name. So i need to know ahead of the insert which are new and which are existing. I guess I could have selectize send the name instead of the id for the existing ones so they are the same column on insert.

Comment: @CharlesEF got it working; pretty slick actually b/c the `REPLACE INTO` always returns the `insert_id` so I don't need to do more tricky loops to next go insert the id's into the mapping table. Thx for help.

Comment: Glad you got it working.